# Subroutines in C#

Tags: c#, function, call, subroutine

I'm a bit new to C#, and not quite sure how to call a subroutine. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call whatever subroutine you like
    StartExstream();
}

public void StartExstream()
{
    // Do Stuff Here
}
```

Unfortunately for me, this doesn't work. I'm getting a "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" error.

How do I call my StartExstream sub from my Button1_Click event?

Thanks,
Jason

**EDIT:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call whatever subroutine you like
         StartExstream();
    }



    public void StartExstream()
    {
        tcpExstream.Service1Client MyTCP = new tcpExstream.Service1Client();

        string ExStreamPath;
        string datPath;
        string optPath;

        // My Working Arguments
        ExStreamPath = @"C:\Program Files\Exstream\Dialogue 6.1\Engine.exe";
        datPath = @"-FILEMAP=DataFile,\\Dev-srv1\Exstream\LetterWriterApp\Input Files\Data Files\SAVEezkazivaftf40s452ndayb45.dat";
        optPath = @"-CONTROLFILE=C:\Exstream\Development\LetterWriter\ControlFiles\Letter.opt";

        // Hong's Arguments
        //ExStreamPath = @"C:\Program Files\Exstream\Dialogue 6.1\Engine.exe";
        //datPath = @"-FILEMAP=DataFile,C:\Exstream\development\AGDocGenerator\TempFiles\DataFiles\Data_456231_1598.xml";
        //optPath = @"-CONTROLFILE=C:\Exstream\development\AGDocGenerator\ExstreamDialogue\ControlFiles\AGDocGenerator.opt";

        // Kick It!
        MyTCP.StartExStream(datPath, optPath, ExStreamPath);

        // Extra line of code for breaking point
        optPath = "nothing";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Code looks fine, you must have omitted the code with the problem

Comment: Post the full class code. The code you have here looks fine.

Comment: I dont see any problem in your code. Please post the full code of the caller and callee functions if you want the people here to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

If the Routine is in the same class than there you can directly call the routine by just writing name of it

```
Example

private void AnotherMethod()
    {
        // Call whatever subroutine you like
         MyRutine();
    }
```

**Second**

If its not in the same class you need to create instance of the class which contains routine and than you can use that object to call you routine

```
Example

MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.MyRutine();
```

Comment: The weird part -- I kept getting the aforementioned error until I deleted the (empty) line of code above it and the (empty) line of code below it. Retyped it and -- Bingo! No error. Strange. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to have this all in a namespace and then in a class for this to work.

```
namespace some.namespace
{
   public class myclass
   {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         // Call whatever subroutine you like         
              StartExstream();     
        }
        public void StartExstream()
        {         // Do Stuff Here     
        } 
   }
}
```

Comment: You *do not* need a namespace (but they do need to be in the same class to call without typename or object).

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on the further post,  Your code

```
tcpExstream.Service1Client MyTCP = new tcpExstream.Service1Client();
```

is trying to create an object of a type that isn't a type but a member of a type.

instead you would use something like

```
WhateverTypeTcpExstreamIs MyTCP = new WhateverTypeTcpExstreamIs();
MyTCP.Service1Client = tcpExstream.Service1Client();
```